# jQuery's val() returns empty string on bootstrap popover input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap popup form with a few input fields. I've added a submit button to the form, that triggers client-side JS validation. However, when the button is clicked, the current value of the input fields is not captured by jQuery's val() method: I just get an empty string.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="popover fade right in" style="top: -154.5px; left: 249px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">New Job Site contact</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <form class="popover-form form-horizontal" id="newjobsite_contact_form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://dev.temperature/home/#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class=" required ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="popover-first_name" required="1" placeholder="First name" value="" name="first_name">
                </div>
                <div class=" required ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="1" placeholder="Surname" value="" name="surname">
                </div>
                <div class=" required ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="1" placeholder="Phone" value="" name="phone">
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" value="" name="mobile">
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Website" value="" name="website">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popover_buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit_newjobsite_contact(); return false;" type="button" id="newjobsite_contact_submit">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="close_newjobsite_contact(); return false;" type="button" id="newjobsite_contact_cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function submit_newjobsite_contact() {
    errors_found = validate_popover_form($('#newjobsite_contact_form'));

    if (errors_found.length == 0) {
        // Form values submitted to PHP code through AJAX request here 
    } else {
        error_msg = "Please check the following errors:\n";
        $(errors_found).each(function(key, item) {
            error_msg += "- "+item.message+"\n";
        });
        alert(error_msg);
    }
}

function validate_popover_form(form_element) {
    found_errors = [];
    $('span.error').remove();

    form_element.find('select,input').each(function(key, item) {
        if ($(item).attr('required') && $(item).val().length == 0) {
            found_error = true;
            found_errors.push({elementname: $(item).attr('name'), message: "A value for "+$(item).attr('placeholder')+" is required"});
        }

        console.log($(item).val()); // More validation here, just putting debugging code instead
    });
    return found_errors;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All other attributes for these input fields are being correctly retrieved by jQuery, just not the value after I've typed text into them.

Comment: Strangely this works fine when I take it out into a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EuLR4/5/), but it doesn't work on my own page. I'm guessing that bootstrap's popover JS is messing up with jquery in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem couldn't be found here because I didn't post the whole source JS, which is too large. What really happened is that I accidentally cloned the popover form, which led to a duplication of the input fields.

Comment: Oh men I was doing the same error and it took me a while to figure out that I cloned the form! your answer helped me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
form_element.find('select,input').each(function(key, item) {
        if ($(item).attr('required') && $(item).val().length == 0) {
            found_error = true;
            found_errors.push({elementname: $(item).attr('name'), message: "A value for "+$(item).attr('placeholder')+" is required"});
        }
```

I Modified it to:

```
    form_element.find('select,input').each(function(key, item) {
            if ($(this).data('required') == '1' && $(this).val().length == 0) {
                found_error = true;
                found_errors.push({elementname: $(this).attr('name'), message: "A value for "+$(this).attr('placeholder')+" is required"});
}
```

Try using data attributes so instead of using `required="1"` use `data-required="1"`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required="1" placeholder="Surname" value="" name="surname">
```

so your input should be like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-required="1" placeholder="Surname" value="" name="surname">
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue. I'm using this form's inputs to submit an AJAX request. As you can see in the button's onclick event handler, it is set to return false regardless, so that takes care of preventing a normal submit event. I want to capture these inputs, validate them client-side, then send them off by POST to a PHP function.

Comment: @NicolasConnault maybe you want to recheck what you have putted , i don't see your submit to have `return false;` but cancel has. I don't see an ajax also.Anyways ill provide an alternative solution for your validate_popover_form

Comment: You're correct, I made a mistake in copying my code here. It doesn't change the issue though. I've removed the AJAX call because it's irrelevant to the issue here. As the validation fails regardless of the input's values, the AJAX code never runs.

Comment: @NicolasConnault updated answer. See if it will work

Comment: No sorry that doesn't address the actual issue. The "required" condition works as expected, using your code or mine. It's the val() method that doesn't work as expected (second condition in the validation code). 
`$(item).val()` just returns an empty string, even if that input has text in it. I even tested by adding a unique ID to the element, and using that as the jquery selector: still no value.

Comment: if you alert `.attr('required')` it will alert 'required' and so your if statement will not work , .val() has nothing to do with it since it is correct

Comment: Just notice it , your `<div>` has the required class and not in the input?